# The name of my wireless card keeps switching randomly on reboot

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I'm using Arch Linux on a Dell laptop. My wireless card was always named `wlp*`. Then after I installed something—which I don't remember (maybe some connection manager?)—and my wireless card randomly switched between `wlp*` and `wlan0` upon reboot and has being doing that since then.

This is mainly annoying since I have a network monitor widget in my panel, and it requires me to actively change the card's name every time that happens.

How can I find out *what* is changing the name, and more importantly, how to make it stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How can I find out what is changing the name**

Network managers *should not* change the name of an interface. Drivers do this kind of thing.

```
dmesg | grep renamed
```

as root might give insight as to what as doing this.

As per [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180057) ArchLinux question:

> Mine does that sometimes too...
> This behaviour can be disabled by adding
>
> ```
> net.ifnames=0
> ```
>
> in your kernel command line, or mask udev's rule file:
>
> ```
> ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
> ```
>
> See [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) for more on this

Alternatively, you could write a udev rule to try to keep it the same:

`SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="[MAC of your WLAN card]", NAME="wlan0"`

Write it to `/etc/udev/rules.d/98-persist-interface.rules`

Comment: I've tried the udev option, it seems to work. I'll wait a few more reboots before I'm sure it's gone. But the dmesg doesn't show a renamed so that's good! Thanks!

Comment: Three reboots or so, seems to work! Thanks a lot!